# Nuxt modules state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have an nuxt app with modules state:

- Store

  - index.js, state.js, mutations.js, actions.js, getters.js
  - Modules

    - Posts
    - index.js, state.js, mutations.js, actions.js, getters.js

In Store/index.js I have:

```
import state from './state'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as getters from './getters'

import posts from './modules/posts'

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  modules: {
    posts
  }
}
```

Inside Store/state.js I have:

```
export default () => ({
  test: null
})
```

Inside Store/Modules/Posts/index.js I have:

```
import state from './state'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as getters from './getters'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

And inside Store/Modules/Posts/state.js I have:

```
export default () => ({
  dialog: false,
  test: false
})
```

My store now has duplicated everything from getters, actions etc.
Should it be that way or not? Am I using store how I should or not?
When I remove modules from base inldex.js I have one of everything but then, everything is undefined.

Store output example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 'modules' folder at all. Nuxt is clever enough to puzzle together your store from the files and directory structure. So, your example could be like this:

- Dir: store

  - state.js, mutations.js, actions.js, getters.js
  - Dir: posts

    - state.js, mutations.js, actions.js, getters.js

Note that you don't need the index.js files either! In fact, if your store doesn't have a specific root state, then no need to have the files under the store directory.

The docs are a bit vague on what should be in each file. Here is a quick guide:

```js
state.js
export default () => ({
  field1: 'init value',
  field2: 'init value'
})
```

```js
mutations.js
export function mutation1(state, payload) {...}
export function mutation2(state, payload) {...}
```

```js
getters.js
export getter1(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {...}
export getter2(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {...}
```

```js
actions.js
export action1(context, payload) {...}
export action2(context, payload) {...}
```